# Can I push a tag to current pushed git?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-tag

Is it possible to push a tag to currently pushed file in github? I have searched through Google but no clue at all. Thanks!

Comment: tags in git are on commits, not files. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: You can stick a tag on any git object. It doesn't have to be a commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** As Abizern and fork0 mentioned in the comments, you can tag any git object. In any case, `git push --tags <remote> <branch>` will solve the problem.

--

As Shahbaz has mentioned tags are for commits, not files. If you're asking about pushing a tag to an already pushed *commit*, yes, you can do that. Create the tag (using `git tag`) and enter,

```
git push --tags <remote> <branch>
```

Replace <remote> with the remote name (eg: *origin*) and <branch> with the branch name (eg: *master*). This will push all local tags in <branch> that haven't been pushed before.

Comment: Not strictly true. You can put a tag on any git object. If you have a sha such as `abcd12` you can tag it with `git tag -a someTagName -m"some message describing the tag" abcd12`. Tags are *usually* used for commits, but they don't need to be.

Comment: Just for the record: you can tag anything, including data of a file (blob object), data of a tree (directory), or even a tag object itself. The Git repository has such tags, i.e. junio-gpg-pub (the maintainers GPG pubkey)

Comment: Indeed. I wrote a description of how to add a key to a repository: http://365git.tumblr.com/post/2813251228/adding-a-gpg-public-key-to-a-repository

Comment: @Abizern, fork0: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any method to get the SHA of a non-commit-object easily?

Comment: Ah got it, it's `git hash-object`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your answer and comments..I'm managed to solve it by simply doing what Abizem said, then thameera said..Also thanks for new knowledge that fork0 and Abizem share..